# what is the difference between derivative and differentiation?

Tags: derivatives, definition

I want to know more about what is the difference， both in single variable and multivariable， I want to know about the general definition if there is one.
I will appreciate it if someone can help me!!
thx!!

Comment: derivative is a mathematical object, a function, differentiation is an action. The derivative of $f$ is $f$ after it is differentiated.

Comment: differentiation = baking;
derivative = cake

Answer (score 1):

A derivative is what you get as a result of differentiation.  This is more a matter of language than mathematics.  It's the same as the difference between 'product' and 'production', one is process, the other is the result of that process.

Comment: thanks!! it is easy to understand, it help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Derivative at point $x$ is the current name for the rate of variation of a function at point $x$. It was once called *differential coefficient* and is still written $\frac {dy}{dx}$ where $d$ means a small variation (a small difference).

Differentiation is the process of finding a function $f'$, called the derivative of $f$, which describes this rate of variation for any point $x$. E.g. the differentiation of $f(x) = 2x^4+5$ results in the derivative $f'(x) = 6x^3$.

If the function can be described by a curve, then the rate of variation (the derivative) at point $x$ is the slope of the tangent at point $x$.